# How can I have the menu open by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have a slide out menu that I want to be open by default and can't be closed. I tried changing it from `open=true` to `open=false` but nothing happened. Here's the code below.I want to remove the open and close button so then it'll sort of be "embedded" in the HTML. Here's the menu in action. help.colourity.com. Any help would be much appreciated

JS:

```
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    // taken from https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js
    function hasParent( e, id ) {
        if (!e) return false;
        var el = e.target||e.srcElement||e||false;
        while (el && el.id != id) {
            el = el.parentNode||false;
        }
        return (el!==false);
    }

    // returns the depth of the element "e" relative to element with id=id
    // for this calculation only parents with classname = waypoint are considered
    function getLevelDepth( e, id, waypoint, cnt ) {
        cnt = cnt || 0;
        if ( e.id.indexOf( id ) >= 0 ) return cnt;
        if( classie.has( e, waypoint ) ) {
            ++cnt;
    }
    return e.parentNode && getLevelDepth( e.parentNode, id, waypoint, cnt );
}

// http://coveroverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
function mobilecheck() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
}

// returns the closest element to 'e' that has class "classname"
function closest( e, classname ) {
    if( classie.has( e, classname ) ) {
        return e;
    }
    return e.parentNode && closest( e.parentNode, classname );
}

function mlPushMenu( el, trigger, options ) {   
    this.el = el;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.options = extend( this.defaults, options );
    // support 3d transforms
    this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
    if( this.support ) {
        this._init();
    }
}

mlPushMenu.prototype = {
    defaults : {
        // overlap: there will be a gap between open levels
        // cover: the open levels will be on top of any previous open level
        type : 'overlap', // overlap || cover
        // space between each overlaped level
        levelSpacing : 40,
        // classname for the element (if any) that when clicked closes the current level
        backClass : 'mp-back'
    },
    _init : function() {
        // if menu is open or not
        this.open = false;
        // level depth
        this.level = 0;
        // the moving wrapper
        this.wrapper = document.getElementById( 'mp-pusher' );
        // the mp-level elements
        this.levels = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'div.mp-level' ) );
        // save the depth of each of these mp-level elements
        var self = this;
        this.levels.forEach( function( el, i ) { el.setAttribute( 'data-level', getLevelDepth( el, self.el.id, 'mp-level' ) ); } );
        // the menu items
        this.menuItems = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) );
        // if type == "cover" these will serve as hooks to move back to the previous level
        this.levelBack = Array.prototype.slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.' + this.options.backClass ) );
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        this.eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        // add the class mp-overlap or mp-cover to the main element depending on options.type
        classie.add( this.el, 'mp-' + this.options.type );
        // initialize / bind the necessary events
        this._initEvents();
    },
    _initEvents : function() {
        var self = this;

        // the menu should close if clicking somewhere on the body
        var bodyClickFn = function( el ) {
            self._resetMenu();
            el.removeEventListener( self.eventtype, bodyClickFn );
        };

        // open (or close) the menu
        this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            if( self.open ) {
                self._resetMenu();
            }
            else {
                self._openMenu();
                // the menu should close if clicking somewhere on the body (excluding clicks on the menu)
                document.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                    if( self.open && !hasParent( ev.target, self.el.id ) ) {
                        bodyClickFn( this );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // opening a sub level menu
        this.menuItems.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            // check if it has a sub level
            var subLevel = el.querySelector( 'div.mp-level' );
            if( subLevel ) {
                el.querySelector( 'a' ).addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                    if( self.level <= level ) {
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        classie.add( closest( el, 'mp-level' ), 'mp-level-overlay' );
                        self._openMenu( subLevel );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // closing the sub levels :
        // by clicking on the visible part of the level element
        this.levels.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            el.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                var level = el.getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                if( self.level > level ) {
                    self.level = level;
                    self._closeMenu();
                }
            } );
        } );

        // by clicking on a specific element
        this.levelBack.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            el.addEventListener( self.eventtype, function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' );
                if( self.level <= level ) {
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    self.level = closest( el, 'mp-level' ).getAttribute( 'data-level' ) - 1;
                    self.level === 0 ? self._resetMenu() : self._closeMenu();
                }
            } );
        } );    
    },
    _openMenu : function( subLevel ) {
        // increment level depth
        ++this.level;

        // move the main wrapper
        var levelFactor = ( this.level - 1 ) * this.options.levelSpacing,
            translateVal = this.options.type === 'overlap' ? this.el.offsetWidth + levelFactor : this.el.offsetWidth;

        this._setTransform( 'translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)' );

        if( subLevel ) {
            // reset transform for sublevel
            this._setTransform( '', subLevel );
            // need to reset the translate value for the level menus that have the same level depth and are not open
            for( var i = 0, len = this.levels.length; i < len; ++i ) {
                var levelEl = this.levels[i];
                if( levelEl != subLevel && !classie.has( levelEl, 'mp-level-open' ) ) {
                    this._setTransform( 'translate3d(-100%,0,0) translate3d(' + -1*levelFactor + 'px,0,0)', levelEl );
                }
            }
        }
        // add class mp-pushed to main wrapper if opening the first time
        if( this.level === 1 ) {
            classie.add( this.wrapper, 'mp-pushed' );
            this.open = true;
        }
        // add class mp-level-open to the opening level element
        classie.add( subLevel || this.levels[0], 'mp-level-open' );
    },
    // close the menu
    _resetMenu : function() {
        this._setTransform('translate3d(0,0,0)');
        this.level = 0;
        // remove class mp-pushed from main wrapper
        classie.remove( this.wrapper, 'mp-pushed' );
        this._toggleLevels();
        this.open = false;
    },
    // close sub menus
    _closeMenu : function() {
        var translateVal = this.options.type === 'overlap' ? this.el.offsetWidth + ( this.level - 1 ) * this.options.levelSpacing : this.el.offsetWidth;
        this._setTransform( 'translate3d(' + translateVal + 'px,0,0)' );
        this._toggleLevels();
    },
    // translate the el
    _setTransform : function( val, el ) {
        el = el || this.wrapper;
        el.style.WebkitTransform = val;
        el.style.MozTransform = val;
        el.style.transform = val;
    },
    // removes classes mp-level-open from closing levels
    _toggleLevels : function() {
        for( var i = 0, len = this.levels.length; i < len; ++i ) {
            var levelEl = this.levels[i];
            if( levelEl.getAttribute( 'data-level' ) >= this.level + 1 ) {
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-open' );
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-overlay' );
            }
            else if( Number( levelEl.getAttribute( 'data-level' ) ) == this.level ) {
                classie.remove( levelEl, 'mp-level-overlay' );
            }
        }
    }
}

// add to global namespace
window.mlPushMenu = mlPushMenu;

} )( window );
```

Comment: It's impossible to have a slide-out menu that is always open and can't be closed. I mean, that would be a menu, not a slide-out menu.

Comment: @MrLister I fixed my issue and now have a menu instead of a slide out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using mlpushmenu.
Call ._openMenu() to have the menu open at start.

```
        var menu = new mlPushMenu( 
            document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), 
            document.getElementById( 'trigger' ));
        menu._openMenu();
```

After that remove any buttons that close the menu.